# Reporting progress for a depth-first traversal

Tags: c#, tree, spreadsheet, depth-first-search, epplus

Is it possible to calculate and report progress for a task that is performed using a depth-first traversal of a tree structure? In particular, it is a program that traverses a tree structure and creates a spreadsheet with C# and EPPlus and writes the data in the tree to that spreadsheet.

This is performed in a `BackgroundWorker`. (I know that a `Task` would be recommended instead, however BackgroundWorkers are used throughout the project and cannot be changed). `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress()` is used to update a progress bar in the WinForms app.

This is the code for performing this task (at least, the important bits of code). As commented in the code, the number of "nodes" in the tree out of the total written to the spreadsheet forms the basis of the progress.

```
public void render(ref System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker worker)
{
    // create a new worksheet
    OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("revisions");

    // write the metadata
    // ...

    // write the headers
    // ...

    // perform a depth first traversal of the structure

    Queue<Node> traversalState = new Queue<Node>();
    rowNumber = HEADER;
    foreach (Node node in revisions)
    {
        traversalState.Enqueue(node);
    }

    while (traversalState.Count > 0)
    {
        // get the node from the queue
        Node currNode = traversalState.Dequeue();

        // do stuff with it
        // want to report progress for this, that is how many "nodes" are written to the spreadsheet
        worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value = node.getPath();
        worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value = node.getDescription();
        
        // put the node's children onto the queue
        foreach (Node newNode in node)
        {
            traversalState.Enqueue(newNode);
        }

        rowNumber++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code actually looks like Breadth First, giving you no idea how deep the tree might be. If it was Depth First, you could probably estimate the percentage of the tree you had traversed. Of course you could count the nodes and maybe queue them all first. Or just cheat and use something like `1 - 1/elapsed time`

Comment: You are generating revisions? Do you know the element count ahead of time?

Comment: If not, depending on the complexity of the traversal it could be an option to have a first pass to retreive the number of elements. If the tree is ballenced you would only need to traverse one branch for instance.

Comment: @Jason I have a `List` of "revisions" at my disposal, so I can get the count from that. The problem is I don't know how to keep track of how many nodes have been dealt with while the traversal is in progress.

Comment: If you know the total node count then you can just have a counter that you increment whenever you Dequeue.